# Organizing data from Database in a map with Columnnames

Tags: java, orm

I am trying to organize data from an database. The tables im trying to map look like this:

```
Id | Timestamp | dataOne | dataTwo |dataThree | ... | dataN
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 12.04.2017| 123     | 1231232 | 123213   | 112 | 123
------------------------------------------------------------- 
2 .....
```

Im interested in all the data, only the id is not neccessary. I have multiple tables like these, and all of them will be put into different charts, but the tables all have different column names, since the data sources are nearly the same, but not to 100%. Thats why I can't implement every table as entity and need to do it dynamically, which is why I thought of a Hashmap to collect the data.

I thought of a HashMap that would look like this:

For Example

```
hashMap
Timestamp: values[] // Cotaining all the Timestamp values
dataOne: values[] // Containing all the dataOne values
...
```

The problem here is, I don't have a good way to retrieve the column names for the map to let my algorithm later know, what to do with each value according to its purpose.

I wanted to ask if my way is bad practice or if anyone of you has done something similiar and can give me a hint here, how to do this proper.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the values in hashmap like timestamp: values(). You can crate the pojo corresponding to the table structure and then store it in hashmap where key is the primary key of the row and its value is the pojo with remaining content of the row. Now whenever you need any data you can get it with the help primary key

Example :- 
Map map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(id, obj);

Hope it will be helpful!!